# How to run python function every 1 sec in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I was thinking to use multiprocess package to run a function in parallel but I need to pass a different value of parameter every run (every 1 sec).

e.g.)

```
def foo(list):
  while True:
    <do something with list>
    sleep(1000)

def main():
  process = multiprocess.Process(target=foo, args=(lst))
  process.start()

  <keep updating lst>
```

This will cause a foo() function running with the same parameter value over and over. How can I work around in this scenario?

Comment: If you update `lst` in your parent process, it won't automatically reflect into a `multiprocessing` child process, so this doesn't help you much...

Comment: Got it. What other options do I have then?

Comment: What do you want to _do_, in the end?

Comment: I want to run foo() function concurrently while passing a different param value while main() function updates that parameter variable..

Comment: Yes, but _why_? What should the function do? Are you maybe actually looking for a `threading.Queue` or `multiprocessing.Queue` to pass work with?

Comment: The foo function does an http post call to save some logs (batch) to the storage. The main function is getting text logs (save log to the batch) while running a given shell script. Basically, I'm trying to do batching for logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Armed with the knowledge of what you're actually trying to do, i.e.

> The foo function does an http post call to save some logs (batch) to the storage. The main function is getting text logs (save log to the batch) while running a given shell script. Basically, I'm trying to do batching for logging.

the answer is to use a thread and a queue for message passing (`multiprocessing.Process` and `multiprocessing.Queue` would also work, but aren't really necessary):

```
import threading
import time
from queue import Queue


def send_batch(batch):
    print("Sending", batch)


def save_worker(queue: Queue):
    while True:
        batch = queue.get()
        if batch is None:  # stop signal
            break
        send_batch(batch)
        queue.task_done()


def main():
    batch_queue = Queue()
    save_thread = threading.Thread(target=save_worker, args=(batch_queue,))
    save_thread.start()
    log_batch = []

    for x in range(42):  # pretend this is the shell script outputting things
        message = f"Message {x}"
        print(message)
        log_batch.append(message)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if len(log_batch) >= 7:  # could also look at wallclock
            batch_queue.put(log_batch)
            log_batch = []
    if log_batch:
        batch_queue.put(log_batch)  # send the last batch
    print("Script stopped, waiting for worker to finish")
    batch_queue.put(None)  # stop signal
    save_thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import threading
import time

def run_every_second(param):
    # your function code here
    print(param)

# create a list of parameters to pass to the function
params = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# create and start a thread for each parameter
for param in params:
    t = threading.Thread(target=run_every_second, args=(param,))
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)

# wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

This will create a new thread for each parameter, and each thread will run the run_every_second function with the corresponding parameter. The threads will run concurrently, so the functions will be executed in parallel. There will be a 1-second time lapse between the start of each thread.

Comment: Quick question. Is there a reason why threading is better than multiprocessing in this scenario?

Comment: I didn't really think about it, but in general, if you need to run a large number of concurrent I/O-bound tasks, threading may be a good choice. If you need to run a small number of concurrent CPU-bound tasks, or if you need to run tasks concurrently with tasks written in other languages, multiprocessing may be a better choice.